# jQuery Animate toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I am trying to create an animate effect like the following.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lovebtn').click(function () {
        $('.love').animate({
            height: '672px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('.lovetxt').css("display", "block");
            $(".lovebtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_love_close.gif");

        });

    });


    // Lust
    $('.lustbtn').click(function () {
        $('.lust').animate({
            height: '672px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('.lusttxt').css("display", "block");
            $(".lustbtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_lust_close.gif");

        });

    });


    //luxuary
    // Lust
    $('.luxurybtn').click(function () {
        $('.maskbg').css("display", "block");
        $('.luxury').animate({
            height: '1056px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('.luxurytxt').css("display", "block");
            $(".luxurybtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_luxury_close.gif");

        });

    });
});
```

http://uniquedl.com/3closets/index.html

when you go the the ablove page and click the three buttons on either love lust and luxury. you get a series of effects. when i click the same button i wannt reverse the effect .

any tips how i can do it ?

Comment: Could you post that on a collaborative site, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), where we can experiment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will show only for the love buttonm almost the same for other just different height and CSS selectors of course

```
$('.lovebtn').click(
     $('.love').toggle(  
         function() {  
             $('.love').animate({  
                 height: '672px'   
             }, 1000, function () {  
                 $('.lovetxt').css("display", "block");  
                 $(".lovebtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_love_close.gif");  
             }    
        },    
        function() {    
            $('.love').animate({    
                height: '480px'    
            }, 1000, function () {    
                $('.lovetxt').css("display", "none");  
                $(".lovebtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_love_open.gif");  
            }    
        }  
    );  
);
```

Sorry I have problems putting the code in right layout :( You could check it here http://jsfiddle.net/dKyku/

Basically on clicking the link you toggle between two portions of code, one showing the section, and second one hiding it/putting it back to its original layout.

Comment: Don't put `<code>` to format code on SO. Instead, select your code and press the `{}` icon.

Comment: Thank you @Skikiryu. Looks much better :) What is <code> used for then?

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this by adding extra class like this

```
   $('.lovebtn').click(function (){
   if (!$(this).hasClass('reverse')) {
    hasClickedLove = true;
    $('.love').animate({
        height: '672px'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('.lovetxt').css("display", "block");
        $(".lovebtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_love_close.gif");
    });
  $(this).addClass('reverse);

 }//end if
 else if(hasClass('reverse')) {
    $(this).removeClass('reverse);
    //animation code
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Insert a boolean value, like this:

```
$('.lovebtn').click(function () {
    if ( !hasClickedcLove) {
        hasClickedLove = true;
        $('.love').animate({
            height: '672px'
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('.lovetxt').css("display", "block");
            $(".lovebtn .button").attr("src", "images/btn_love_close.gif");
        });
    }//end if
    else {
        hasClickedLove = false;
        //animation code
    }
});
```